# SMTP working POP not working

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces

My domain details are smtp.domainname.com and pop.domainname.com by using these values I can send emails but I cannot receive any emails from other emailing systems. The problem lies at POP obviously. I created a CNAME RECORD as POP.domainname.com but results no use... Do I need to create any other record like A RECORD or MX RECORD or other as POP.domainname.com to receive my mail?

Answer (score 1):

Email servers send and recieve email via SMTP, not POP. Email clients download their email via POP. My suggestion would be to check your public DNS namespace to make sure you have an MX record for your domain and to also check your firewall to make sure you're allowing inbound SMTP traffic to your email server.

Comment: how to check whether my MX record is created or not using public DNS ??....

Comment: You can use MXToolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is DNS-related?
To verify this problem, you must verify the  DNS record is right. I mean, it's pointing to your pop server's Ip.

If it isn't dns-related, you should:
- check logs in the server related to pop. You should look for activity and/or errors.
- you can test pop service from inside the server. Access the server and make a telnet to port 110 and wait for prompt.

Regards

Comment: If the OP is having problems with his server receiving email from other servers then it's not a POP problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about your domain and setup it is hard to say, but start by creating MX records pointing to the host (A) record that points to the IP of the server that you are using to receive mail.

You should also set up reverse DNS (a PTR record) for your SMTP server, as this makes it less likely to be flagged as a source of spam.

Comment: If the OP is having problems with his server receiving email from other servers then it's not a POP problem.

Comment: I assume SMTP server means outgoing and POP server means incoming (I also assume they are not the same server based on what he said). The MX record has to point to the incoming server.

Comment: Email servers send and receieve emails via SMTP, not POP. The OP stated that his server cannot receive emails from other servers, that's an SMTP problem, not a POP problem. POP is a client protocol that email clients use to download email from an email server. POP is not used by email servers in the sending and receiving of emails.

Comment: Hi Joe - I understand that. The OP's description of his server layout is not clear. I've updated my answer to reflect that he must point his MX records *to the server which is receiving his email*. This might be his SMTP server or his POP server (which could be also  running an SMTP daemon), or both servers could be the same.